# Showing PDF inside sandboxed iframe

Tags: html, iframe, xss, sandbox

Is it possible to show PDF using object element inside sandboxed iframe?
For example, In JSFiddle the content is sandboxed and all the sandboxed attributes are allowed but still its not able to render a PDF

```
<object data="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" class="mt-document-view" type="application/pdf">Image not found 2</object>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4gpchL9z/